# In python selenium, how does one find the visibility of an element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I found the `is_visible` method in the Selenium documentation, but I have no idea how to use it. I keep getting errors such as `is_visible needs a selenium instance as the first parameter`.

Also, what is a "locator"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You should use `is_displayed()` instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('gbqfba') #this element is visible
if element.is_displayed():
  print "Element found"
else:
  print "Element not found"

hidden_element = driver.find_element_by_name('oq') #this one is not
if hidden_element.is_displayed():
  print "Element found"
else:
  print "Element not found"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the script that works for me in python3:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

ser = Service(r"C:/Users/geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=ser)

# should open Firefox

driver.get("https://example.com")

# should display home page

try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'footer-block')
    if element.is_displayed():
        break

except:
    continue

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

From here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html

Just use

> selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of

cos

> Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a
> height and width that is greater than 0

Comment: ``visibility_of`` internally uses ``is_displayed()`` so I don't see how your answer is different from the accepted answer. And OP is not asking how to wait for a condition to be met.

Comment: @MikeScotty read the link which I posted, and will understand :)

Comment: I did more than that, I looked at the [implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#visibility_of) - ``visibility_of`` internally ``uses is_displayed()`` Click my link and you will understand.

Comment: @MikeScotty , let me clarify. `is_displayed()` will return Boolean condition is that element is displayed or not. That does not mean, you could use that element. e.g click(), get text and so on. For me, the best way is to use `visibility_of_element_located` cos 
`Visibility means that the element is not only displayed
    but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.`
Which means, could interact with that element.

Comment: Will you please stop repeating the same stuff and just look at the code. ``visibility_of`` calls ``_element_if_visible`` which calls ``element.is_displayed()``. It's just 5 lines of code. I never said that ``is_displayed()`` does not rely on checking width/height of the element to determine the return value. Actually ``is_displayed()`` will execute [this piece of JS](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/atoms/isDisplayed.js) - so it's hard to tell what's actually checked.

Comment: Proof that this piece of JS is actually part of selenium's python distribution: ``import selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement as w;print(w.isDisplayed_js)
``

Comment: Thanks @Zhivko.Kostadinov, this is exactly what I needed since I wanted to employ Selenium's `WebDriverWait` along with an expected condition while not having a locator but the actual web element at hand:
`target_web_element = WebDriverWait(self._driver, MAX_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of(target_web_element), _get_webdriver_wait_error_msg)`