# Quick checking if element exists with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exception, xpath

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937966/in-python-selenium-how-does-one-find-the-visibility-of-an-element#:%7E:text=You%20should%20use%20is_displayed()%20instead%3A) about checking the visibility of an element.
My problem with this answer is, that it never returns "Element not found". Not only that! It take a very long time to give the error message (below).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')


element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/a[2]') #this element exists
if element.is_displayed():
    print("Element found")
else:
    print("Element not found")

hidden_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/a[20]') #this one doesn't exist
if hidden_element.is_displayed():
    print("Element found")
else:
    print("Element not found")
```

I need something that is more efficient and returns False or something another than this error message:

> RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.jsm:12:1 WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:192:5 NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:404:5 element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:291:16

Comment: I need something that very quick checks if an element exist.

Comment: Try a different website, not google.com

Comment: okay @It_is_Chris I will and tell you.

Comment: Unfortantly. Nothing change @It_is_Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `driver.find_element` you can use `driver.find_elements` method.
Something like this:

```py
if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/a[20]'):
    print("Element found")
else:
    print("Element not found")
```

`driver.find_elements` will return you a **list** of web elements matching the passed locator. In case such elements found it will return non-empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean `True` while if no matches found it will give you an empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean `False`.
To reduce the time it takes here you can define `implicitly_wait` to some short value, like 1 or 2 seconds, as following:

```py
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
```

**UPD**
In case you want to check the element displayed status you can get the element from the list by index, something like following:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/a[20]')
if elements:
    print("Element found")
    if elements[0].is_displayed():
        print("Element is also displayed")
else:
    print("Element not found")
```

Comment: thank you very much @prophet you are always there to help. I will try it and tell you,

Comment: But hidden element will not return True for `is_displayed` even if it exists. It's hidden, not displayed

Comment: Great work mr. @Prophet !

Comment: I'm always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can check with length of elements

```
hidden_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/a[20]') #this one doesn't exist
if len(hidden_element)>0:
    print("Element found")
else:
    print("Element not found"
```

)

Comment: You forgot the last `)` outside of the code block

Comment: @Carapace : It was there, but it was editing issue.

Comment: Ah. Why don't you edit it again to put it inside? I am sorry, I guess I just suffer of OCD lol